# ASP.NET controller cannot be called if it uses classes not belonging to BCL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC controller class containing a method named "Func". I have noticed that if I insert inside it simple code such as the following:

```
String s1="foo";
String s2="bee";
return s1+s2;
```

the function is called and executed correctly. But if I use classes not belonging to the Base Class Library, such as in the following code block

```
MongoClient mongo_client = new MongoClient();
IMongoDatabase mongo_database = mongo_client.GetDatabase("dbname");
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> mongo_collection = mongo_database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("colname");
```

the method is not even called. Why? Is it something related to MongoDB?

Comment: Did you change the method signature at all when you added the mongo code?

Comment: no the signature is always the same: it doesn't take any argument and returns a string.

Comment: How do you have routing set up?  Are you using attribute routing or explicit route maps?  There has to be something you're missing because ASP.NET is just looking at method signatures and routing information, I don't think it is even possible for it to know what code is inside (nor would it even care).

Comment: I use a map route. In the method Configure I have "app.UseMvc(m=> { m.MapRoute(name:"default", template:"{controller}/{action}/{id?}"); });"

Comment: No compiler errors, no runtime exceptions, nothing like that?

Comment: no it builds correctly

Comment: Yea, there has to be something you're missing, I can't think of any reason why changing the code _inside_ the method would have the effect you're describing.